# SignalR JavaScript Not Connecting

Tags: javascript, signalr

I've very new to JavaScript. I'm trying to implement a simple SignalR server callback in JavaScript.

First, the _Layout.cshtml

```
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
```

Next, my Index.html

```
  <body>

        @section scripts
        {
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
            <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {

                    console.log("HELLO WORLD");

                    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://blah:8094/signalr';
                    var proxy = $.connection.DashboardHub;

                    proxy.client.NotifyAllClientsOfChanges = function () {

                        var searchUrl = "Home/GetData";

                        $.ajax({
                            url: searchUrl,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $("#divData").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto', xdomain: true })
                    .done(function () {
                        console.log('Connected.');
                    })
                    .fail(function (e) {
                        console.log('Unable to connect:' + e);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        }

        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
        {
            <div id="divData">
                @{
                    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

                    @grid.GetHtml(
                    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, 
                    columns:
                    grid.Columns
                    (
                        grid.Column(columnName: "SiteId", header: "Site Id", format: @<text>@item.SiteId</text>),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "Instrument", header: "Instrument", format: @<text>@item.InstrumentId</text> ),
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        }

    </body>
```

I see the "HELLO WORLD" console log at the top, yet I don't see either of the Console logs for "Connected" or "Unable to connect"

I see an error in the console that says "Cannot read property 'client' of undefined"

I've followed many SO posts on similar topics and tried many things. I'm not entirely sure that I have this coded correctly.

Anyone see what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post code for your DashboardHub along with when you configure your hub on app start?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the whole function but for starters:

var proxy = $.connection.DashboardHub;

should be

var proxy = $.connection.dashboardHub;

Needs to start with lowercase

Comment: Really? It's Uppercase in the hub.cs file.. [EDIT] I changed it but it didn't have any effect. Same problem exists.

Comment: Yes, even if uppercase - I remember this biting me. From their example. public class ContosoChatHub : Hub  Then client side var myHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub

Comment: Also make sure your script reference to /signalr/hubs is correct See Client Setup [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy)

Answer (score 1):

some mistakes that I catch. first, if you are using a cross domain server as your signalR hubs, then you should include it in you header instead the local one

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://blah:8094/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Second, when you declare the name in client side of SignalR, you HAVE TO use a small case for the first word, even if you set it as an upper case in your server. Means that, if you declare `MyChatHub' in your server, you Will call it as 'myChatHub' in your javascript.

```
var proxy = $.connection.dashboardHub;

proxy.client.notifyAllClientsOfChanges
```

third, why would you use a POST method in your AJAX when it is a GET method?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following URL hope it will help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server